Normal Zeeman effect
In normal Zeeman effect, $\mathbf{L}$ and $\mathbf{S}$ vectors decouple with each other and they precess about $\mathbf{B}$ independently. How $\mathbf{S}$ vectors are cancelled out, whereas $\mathbf{L}$ is alive?
Please give physical interpretation.

The normal Zeeman effect occurs for singlet states, i.e. the total spin is zero.
For example, if an atom has two electrons and their spins are $+\frac{1}{2}$ and $- \frac{1}{2}$, then the total spin for this atom is zero and the normal Zeeman effect occurs when it's placed in external magnetic field. A typical example of the normal Zeeman effect is Cadmium. Its two outer electrons have opposite spins, resulting in a total spin of 0.
So it's easy to see that an atom with only one electron in its outermost shell cannot exhibit the normal Zeeman effect. For example, sodium exhibits the anomalous Zeeman effect in an external magnetic field.
